# svn can't connect to host 'svn.ffmpeg.org':no route to host

Tags: ffmpeg, mplayer

i am newbie to ubuntu i am trying to install ffmpeg flvtool2 mplayer in ubuntu for php while using this command
svn checkout svn://svn.mplayerhq.hu/ffmpeg/trunk ffmpeg
i am getting the error as svn can't connect to host 'svn.ffmpeg.org':no route to  host.

is there any http link to do this command and why i am getting the error

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg switched from SVN to Git on 2011-01-19. See the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for more details, or [HOWTO: Install and use the latest FFmpeg and x264 on Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095) for compile instructions.